# Automate tasks with Python

Tags: python, audio, automation, pydub

I am looking for a way to automate tasks in external programs with Python.

I have large audio files in AAC format. I need to convert them to mp3, and then amplify them (avoiding the distortion).

I wrote a program with the pydub library that works great with small files, but my files are too large (longer than 2hs or 200mb) and I run out of memory (because that lib store the full files in RAM, I think). I can't split the file in chunks because I could not merge them again for the previous reason, and I need the file in one piece.

So, I would like to write a program that open another program to convert the file to mp3 (mediahuman audio converter) and then, amplify the converted file with another program (WavePad audio editor) but i don't know if is this possible.

In the present, I'm doing that manually, but that takes a long time of waiting and requires less than 10 clicks (spread throughout the process), which is tedious.

I leave the program I wrote. I transcribed it to remove some functions that are not relevant and are not related to this process, plus I translated the comments, variables and other things into English, so it may have some errors but the original program works well:

```
import glob
import os
from pydub import AudioSegment

#convert to mp3 128 bits
sound = AudioSegment.from_file("input-file.aac")
sound.export("output-file.mp3", format="mp3", bitrate="128k")

#sound.max_dBFS shows how far below the limit the highest sample is (in dB)
sound = AudioSegment.from_file("output.mp3", format="mp3")
max_gain_without_distortion = -1 * sound.max_dBFS

#increase volume by "max_gain_without_distortion" dB
from pydub.playback import play
song = AudioSegment.from_mp3("output-file.mp3")
louder_song = song + max_gain_without_distortion

#save louder song
louder_song.export("output.mp3", format='mp3')
```

PC specifications: ///
OS: windows 10 pro 64 bits ///
RAM: 4gb ///
CPU: dualcore 3ghz ///
PYTHON VERSION: 3.7.1 ///
Pydub version: v0.23.1-0-g46782a9 ///
ffmpeg/avlib version:  "Build: ffmpeg-20190219-ff03418-win32-static" ///

Comment: As much as I love Python, using `sox` would be far more efficient. If you're bent on Python, you can use `pysox`. If you like I can answer how to do that with `sox` - it's one of the best tools out there for such operations.

Comment: Hi @lukasz-tracewski that would be great! I only put python because it's the language I know, but anyone else is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Done. Just a side note to earlier comment: since `sox` does not work with *aac*, I proposed *ffmpeg* instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As agreed in comments, as a solution I am going to propose using a command line tool: [FFmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/). Here's the command you need:

`ffmpeg -i input-file.aac -b:v 128k -filter:a loudnorm output.mp3`

using [loudnorm](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioVolume). You can also apply gain directly as explained in the docs, but one should expect inferior results. Normalization can be done in number of ways, I suggest reading [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/323119/how-can-i-normalize-audio-using-ffmpeg).

By combining it with e.g. `find . -name '*.wav' -type f` you can easily find and convert all files in a directory tree.

If you're bent on using Python, you can check [Python bindings](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python). Basics:

```
import ffmpeg
ffmpeg.input('stereo.aac').output('mono.mp3').run()
```

Initially I was going to propose using [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/): *Sound eXchange, the Swiss Army knife of audio manipulation*. It's not Python, though has [Python bindings](https://github.com/rabitt/pysox): *pysox*. However, it turned out it does not support aac format (still has dozens of other formats). I thought it could be interesting to mention it anyway, as one could convert first to more popular format with *ffmpeg* and pipe results to *sox*. The latter has many more options for modification of audio stream.

Convert wav to mp3 and resample to 128kbit:

`sox -r 128k input-file.wav output-file.mp3`

The OP asks to "increase volume by max_gain_without_distortion dB" and for this we can use either `gain` or `norm` as explained in [docs](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html):

`sox -r 128k input-file.wav output-file.mp3 gain −n -3`

After docs, *The −n option normalises the audio to 0dB FSD; it is often used in conjunction with a negative gain-dB to the effect that the audio is normalised to a given level below 0dB*.

`sox −−norm -r 128k input-file.wav output-file.mp3`